# Cannot install / restore mysqli with php@8.x using Homebrew

Tags: php, macos, mysqli, homebrew

I am trying to connect my PHP Laravel app using Illuminate to a MySQL database.  To do this, I need the mysqli extension to work.  However, after uncommenting the line to do so in my php.ini file:

`extension=mysqli.so`

...even this results in many commands (e.g. `php --ini`, etc.) resulting in the following output:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mysqli' (tried: /opt/homebrew/lib/php/pecl/20220829/mysqli (dlopen(/opt/homebrew/lib/php/pecl/20220829/mysqli, 0x0009): tried: '/opt/homebrew/lib/php/pecl/20220829/mysqli' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/opt/homebrew/lib/php/pecl/20220829/mysqli' (no such file), '/opt/homebrew/lib/php/pecl/20220829/mysqli' (no such file)), /opt/homebrew/lib/php/pecl/20220829/mysqli.so (dlopen(/opt/homebrew/lib/php/pecl/20220829/mysqli.so, 0x0009): tried: '/opt/homebrew/lib/php/pecl/20220829/mysqli.so' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/opt/homebrew/lib/php/pecl/20220829/mysqli.so' (no such file), '/opt/homebrew/lib/php/pecl/20220829/mysqli.so' (no such file))) in Unknown on line 0
```

Some investigation of these directories on my mac lead me to believe that:

1. My machine is missing some necessary `mysqli.so` file.
2. Whenever I try to install the missing library, homebrew complains that there is no such library/extension called "mysqli":

```
ryan@Ryans-MacBook-Pro ~ % brew install php-mysqli

Warning: No available formula with the name "php-mysqli". Did you mean php-zts?
==> Searching for similarly named formulae and casks...
==> Formulae
shivammathur/php/php-zts

To install shivammathur/php/php-zts, run:
  brew install shivammathur/php/php-zts
```

I expect there must be *some* way to install mysqli onto my mac...

Comment: install mysql like this `brew install mysql`

Comment: @RobertMihaiIonas Yeah, I've definitely tried that as well as `brew reinstall mysql`, but that doesn't help.  Thanks though.

Comment: Did you try `brew search php` or `brew search mysqli` ? Perhaps you need to specify the php version, e.g. `brew install php8-mysqli`

Answer (score 0):

The ini entry `extension=mysqli.so` is required if `mysqli` is compiled as a shared extension.

All PHP brew formulae compile `mysqli` statically with the PHP binary, so this line is not required and should be removed. That will remove the PHP Warning you are getting.

Then, to check if `mysqli` is loaded correctly, you can run the `php -m` command.